# Setting variable to compare file modification between multiple dates

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to compare two text files that are date specific, but I'm stumped. I created a test folder that has three text files in it with modified dates between one and 35 days old.

I.E: red.txt is 35 days old, blue.txt is one day old, and green.txt is 15 days old.

For my two compared files, the first file must be between a range of 13-15 days and the second one day old or less. So for this example, 'green.txt' will become 'file1' and 'blue.txt' will become 'file2' and then be compared with `difflib`, but I'm having trouble with the syntax, or maybe even the logic. I am using `datetime` with `timedelta` to try to get this working, but my results will always store the oldest modified file that is past 15 days for 'file1'. Here's my code:

```
import os, glob, sys, difflib, datetime as d

p_path = 'C:/test/Text_file_compare_test/'
f_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(p_path, '*.txt'))
file1 = ''
file2 = ''
min_days_ago = d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=1)
max_days_ago = d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=13 <= 15)

for file in f_list:
    filetime = d.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(file))

    if filetime < max_days_ago:
        file1 = file
    if filetime > min_days_ago:
        file2 = file

with open(file1) as f1, open(file2) as f2:
    d = difflib.Differ()
    result = list(d.compare(f1.readlines(), f2.readlines()))
    sys.stdout.writelines(result)
```

I'm certain there is something wrong with code:

```
max_days_ago = d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=13 <= 15)
```

Maybe I'm just not seeing something in the `datetime` module that's obvious. Can someone shed some light for me? Also, this is on Windows 10 Python 3.7.2. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'm looking at the overall code but the problem with the line you highlighted is that 13 <= 15 is a boolean comparison, which evaluates to True.  Converted to an integer, it is equal to one meaning `d.timedelta(days=13 <= 15)` is equivalent to `d.timedelta(days=1)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vince. I see what you mean there. It looks like 'file1' will always default to a time after 15 days regardless. I'll keep doing some research on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, your `d.timedelta(days=13 <= 15)` isn't quite right as you are assigning days to a boolean value of true, which will be equivalent to `d.timedelta(days=1)`.  You need to store 3 separate time points and do your 13-15 day comparison against two different dates.  The code below demonstrates what you are looking for I believe:

```py
import datetime as d

files = {
    'red': d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=35),
    'blue': d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=0, hours=12),
    'green': d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=14),
}

days_ago_1 = d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=1)
days_ago_13 = d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=13)
days_ago_15 = d.datetime.now() - d.timedelta(days=15)

file1 = None
file2 = None
for file, filetime in files.items():
    if days_ago_13 >= filetime >= days_ago_15:
        file1 = file
    elif filetime > days_ago_1:
        file2 = file
    # need to break out of the loop when we are finished
    if file1 and file2:
        break

print(file1, file2)
```

prints `green blue`

Comment: Thanks Vince! This works perfect when adding the 13 day timedelta to my code. Now my code imports those specific files and compares them as I wanted. You've been a great help!

Comment: thanks for the upvote.  An accepted answer would also be appreciated